# Basic PHP request firing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to teach myself the basics of PHP and seem to me mucking along alright.  I've come across one tutorial that basically describes how to make a blog.  I understand every single part of it except how the code is actually firing the request.

The code below basically deals with all the form data accordingly and then posts it to the specified database.  Fine.  What I don't understand is which bit in that code is actually firing the request to write to the database.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $month = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['month']));
    $date = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['date']));
    $year = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['year']));
    $time = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['time']));
    $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];

    $timestamp = strtotime($month . " " . $date . " " . $year . " " . $time);

    $entry = nl2br($entry);

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $title = addslashes($title);
        $entry = addslashes($entry);
    }

    mysql_connect (localhost,GLA,root) ;
    mysql_select_db (News);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO News (timestamp,title,entry) VALUES ('$timestamp','$title','$entry')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or print("Can't insert into table php_blog.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

    if ($result != false) {
        print "Your entry has successfully been entered into the database.";
    }

    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

As far as I can work out, the `INSERT INTO ...` section, which would generally do the work, is only being stored as the `$result` variable and is not actually being fired.  My instinct would tell me to just have an extra line below the line that defines the `$result` variable that just simply reads `$result`, so as to fire its contents.

However, I know I'm 100% wrong because the script works like a charm!!!

I'm probably missing something very fundamental here but I'd appreciate some sort of explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $result variable is storing the return of the [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function. That is the function which is doing the database work. Then the `$result` variable is simply checked to see if it is not false. If it is false, it means `mysql_query` was not able to process the query.

Comment: Riiiight - I see my problem here.  I'm thinking of the result variable as a string which needs to be fired somehow.  It's actually has to be fired as part of creating the `$result` query.  Thanks for everyone's quick answers - no-one really 'answered' my question per se as it was such an amateurish question but Ianare gave me the push towards the Eureka moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query() is the php function that executes the sql statement stored in $sql
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

The database insert is being triggered by calling mysql_query($sql) where $sql is an insert statement. mysql_query() isn't only used for reading data from the database, but for all inserts, updates, deletes and even table creation, etc; depending on the value ofthe SQL statement contained in $sql

However, the tutorial where you got this example is pretty dated, and doesn't really ensure that your SQL statement is "safe" to use in a real-world script

Comment: I appreciate that cheers Mark.  I imagine that there are a few validation points that may need checking up on throughout the script but for the time being I'm just looking to get the basics down :) it'll be a while before the real world is subject to my PHP coding!

Comment: Would you be able to recommend and more current tutorials for future reference?

Comment: Probably something that uses the more modern mysqli with its prepared statements rather than mysql library, or even PDO... the first couple identified by a google: http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ben_robinson20070314.php3 , http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/12442-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements.html and http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/ ... I'm sure others could offer better suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missing the HTML part which is a form which has

- method which is post
- action which is this script
- a submit button named submit
- and six other input elements named month, date, year, time, title and entry

The whole script fired when the button is pressed (`isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: I understand that there is a form - I just haven't included it here, but the form isn't really relevant.  What I want to know is which part of the script is sending the information to the database because, as far as I can see, the request has only been stored in the `$result` variable but the result variable hasn't been fired?

Comment: it's the `mysql_query` command which feed with `$sql` string that previously built. sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Not a problem - it was a very amateurish question by myself, so was prone to misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0):

**$addedRows = mysql_affected_rows();**

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or print("Can't insert into table php_blog.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

   $addedRows = mysql_affected_rows();

    if ($addedRows >= 1) {
        print "Your entry has successfully been entered into the database.";
    }
```